# Android-How to convert String value of latLng from Firebase back to latLng?

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-maps-markers

In my app, I am trying to have people mark their locations, and have it brought back through Firebase.

This is my code for grabbing the latLng:

```
 final LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
```

I then send the string value of latLng to another activity so it gets sent to the databse:

```
            Intent co_intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, ServerImage.class);
            co_intent.putExtra("pelatlng",String.valueOf(latLng));
            MapsActivity.this.startActivity(co_intent);
```

When I do this, the coordinates gets saved in the Database like this(fake coordinates for obvious reasons):

```
Markers:
coordinates: "lat/lng:(35.000000,119.0000000)"
```

I then got the Databse value so I could bring back the coordinates:

```
mDatabaseMarker=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Markers");
```

Now I am trying to put the saved markers through ChildEventListener like this:

```
refDatabase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
 @Override
 public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {

                );
      mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
          .position(?)

 }
```

However,  I don't know what to put for the marker position.
I could get the value back as a String just fine, but having trouble putting the marker on that location. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I tried, but the coordinates value is blank in the databse

Answer (score 0):

Initially Split values inside brackets as below:

```
String example = "lat/lng:(35.000000,119.0000000)";
     Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\(([^)]+)\\)").matcher(example);
     while(m.find()) {
       from_lat_lng = m.group(1) ;    
     }
```

Once you have String with lat,lon Split it and parse it to double.

```
 String[] gpsVal = from_lat_lng.split(",");
            double lat = Double.parseDouble(gpsVal[0]);
            double lon = Double.parseDouble(gpsVal[1]);
```

After this you can use lat,lon in your marker as below:

```
     Marker a = gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().zIndex(100)
                .position(new LatLng(lat,lon))
```